# Will ubuntu 11.10 support LLVM 3.2

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

I would like to create a simple compiler using LLVM, lex and yacc. I think, it will be a good start for me to this framework. I am using Ubuntu 11.10, 64 bit. Will it support the latest released version LLVM 3.2? What are the steps to compile it in my system? I have implemented an LLVM bitcode generator by changing some lines of toy language code included in LLVM tutorial. Now, I want to implement same grammar using lex and yacc. What must be the changes incorporated?

Answer (score 0):

Clang/LLVM is very easy to build on your own on any modern Ubuntu system. For building from trunk (most up-to-date version of the code), follow the directions at http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

If you don't want to deal with manually checking out code from SVN, download a release tarball from http://llvm.org/releases/download.html